# $x-12\%=100$, find $x$

Tags: education

I need to pay someone after deducting $12\%$ commission. I want to pay him round amount of $10,000$ What is the formula to establish the $112\%$ figure so that once I have deducted my comm I will be left with $10,00$.
I know the answer is not $11200$ because $11200 - 12\% = 9856$.

Please help me with a formula that will calculate $x - 12\%= 10,000$
or $x - 12\% = 7000$  or $x-12\% = 5000$.

Thanks so much,
Maurice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start from a 10% discount and find the original price?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654923/how-do-i-start-from-a-10-discount-and-find-the-original-price)

Answer (score 1):

One may observe that, in general,
$$
x - a\%\:x=b
$$ is just
$$
\left(1-\frac{a}{100} \right)\times x=b
$$ giving, if $a \neq 100$,

> $$
> x=\frac{b}{\left(1-a/100\right)}
> $$

Comment: But in this case it's $x-a\%=b$, not $x-a\%x=b$.

Comment: @user236182: **Errr**... "12% commission" means "12% **times** the total".. so your formula "$x-a\%$" is **wrong** and Olivier's correctly represents what you want.

Comment: I think the OP means $12\%x$ when writing $12\%$.

Comment: I only read what the title said, my bad. The answer to the title question would be $x=\frac{100b+a}{100}$.

Comment: $x-12\%$ is a colloquial/clumsy way to express $x$ less twelve percent *of it*. Deducting $0.12$ would not be expressed as $-12\%$.

Answer (score 1):

$88\%$ of $x$ is $10000$, then $x=\dfrac{10000}{88\%}=10000\cdot\dfrac{100}{88}=11363.63$.

Check: $88\%$ of $11363.63$ is $9999.99$.

Answer (score -1):

see its quite simple sorry for misinterpreting first time. so here we assume total amount to be $x$ thus you want $12\%$ commision of $x$ and extra $10K$. so our equation becomes $\frac{12x}{100}+10000=x$ thus on solving you get $x=11363.63..$ now i hope i have interpreted your question correctly.